# GeoServer, cannot edit existing data access role

Tags: geoserver, configuration

I'm configuring GeoServer and am at the point of editing existing data access roles, these can be found in the 'Data Security' window, there are two at the moment: *.*r, and *.*w.
When I try to edit *.*r, I cannot click on any of the roles in the 'Available Roles' window, see first picture, however I can edit *.*w, see second picture where one role has selected.
There must be a setting somewhere I am missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 2.22.2 - you will need to make sure the `grant access to any role` is unchecked before you can edit them